# Send email with javax.mail using an existing InputStream as attachment content

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, javax.activation

Is it possible to send an email using `javax.mail` and using an “existing” `InputStream` for the email message attachment content?

Currently I am building the email message as follows:

```
final MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
message.setSubject("Subject line");

final Multipart multipartContent = new MimeMultipart();

    final MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    textPart.setText("Message body");
    multipartContent.addBodyPart(textPart);

    final MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    final DataSource source = new InputStreamDataSource("text/plain", "test.txt", new ByteArrayInputStream("CONTENT INPUT STREAM".getBytes()));
    attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    attachmentPart.setFileName("text.txt");
    multipartContent.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);

message.setContent(multipartContent);
```

`InputStreamDataSource` is implemented as follows:

```
public class InputStreamDataSource implements DataSource
{
    private final String contentType;
    private final String name;
    private final InputStream inputStream;

    public InputStreamDataSource(String contentType, String name, InputStream inputStream)
    {
        this.contentType = contentType;
        this.name = name;
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
    }

    public String getContentType()
    {
        return contentType;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("CALLED TWICE: InputStreamDataSource.getInputStream()");
        return new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
        //return new ByteArrayInputStream("THIS 'NEW' INPUT STREAM WORKS BUT 'EXISTING' INPUT STREAM RESULTS IN ZERO-BYTE ATTACHMENT".getBytes());
    }

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented");
    }
}
```

The `DataSource` provides method `getInputStream()` to get the `InputStream` for the email message attachment content.

If I return a "new" `InputStream` which does not depend on an "existing" `InputStream` then it works fine. But if I return an “existing” InputStream then the email message is delivered with a zero-byte attachment.

Is it possible to send an email using `javax.mail`, and use an “existing” `InputStream` for the email message attachment content?

Answer (score 4):

EDIT:

see https://community.oracle.com/thread/1590625

TL;DR use a `ByteArrayDataSource`

---

One has to delve into Oracle's source code... https://java.net/projects/javamail/sources/mercurial/content/mail/src/main/java/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.java

The current java mail implementation goes 2 times over the input stream:

1. First to determine whether it should set the header "Content-Transfer-Encoding" to 7 or 8 bits (see [Content Transfer Encoding 7bit or 8 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25710599/content-transfer-encoding-7bit-or-8-bit))
2. Then a second time when it actually writes the message

...which kind of sucks because the *whole* stream (maybe hundreds of MB over a slow connection) will be read two times ...and leads to exactly this issue for streams that are "consumed" once read.

---

The first "workaround" I tried is to specify the headers yourself:

```
attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
attachmentPart.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8bit");
attachmentPart.setHeader("Content-Type", ds.getContentType() + "; " + ds.getName());
```

...and in that order, and not the other way round ...because for some reason `setDataHandler` calls internally another method `invalidateContentHeaders` which clears the `"Content-Transfer-Encoding"` header again (wtf?!)

Sounded great, the mail was sent, <s>hooray!!! :D</s> ... :( see next

---

*Attachment send ...but broken*

The received file in my mail server is broken. Huh. *Why?!*. After a long search and delving again in this crappy java mail code, I found it, they pipe the `InputStream` into a `LineOutputStream` which changes the line endings of your *binary* data. Meh. The java mail implementation is really a mess. :/

Answer (score 3):

I rewrited your InputStreamDataSource class, and it works for me.

```
class InputStreamDataSource implements DataSource {
    String contentType;
    String name;

    byte[] fileData;

    public InputStreamDataSource(String contentType, String name, InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        this.contentType = contentType;
        this.name = name;
        /**
         * It seems DataSource will close inputStream and reopen it.
         * I converted inputStream to a byte array, so it won't be closed again.
         */
        fileData = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
    }

    public String getContentType() {
        return contentType;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        /**
         * Convert byte array back to inputStream.
         */
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(fileData);
    }

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented");
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems DataSource will close your inputStream and reopen it.  So I converted inputStream to a byte array to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

If the `InputStream` contains mime headers then use the [`javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart(InputStream)`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#MimeBodyPart-java.io.InputStream-) constructor. You don't need to use a custom `DataSource` class.

Otherwise, if the `InputStream` is just the body without headers then convert the stream into a byte array and use the [`javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart(InternetHeaders, byte[])`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#MimeBodyPart-javax.mail.internet.InternetHeaders-byte:A-) constructor to provide your headers.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it converting the `InputStream` to a byte array and converting it to Base64 format.

```
//get file name
String fileName = ...;
//get content type
String fileContentType = ...;
//get file content
InputStream fileStream = ...;

//convert to byte array
byte[] fileByteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(fileStream);
//and convert to Base64
byte[] fileBase64ByteArray = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(fileByteArray);

//manually define headers
InternetHeaders fileHeaders = new InternetHeaders();
fileHeaders.setHeader("Content-Type", fileContentType + "; name=\"" + fileName + "\"");
fileHeaders.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");
fileHeaders.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

//build MIME body part
MimeBodyPart mbp = new MimeBodyPart(fileHeaders, fileBase64ByteArray);
mbp.setFileName(fileName);

//add it to the multipart
multipart.addBodyPart(mbp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for sending email with web downloaded attachment. You can easily edit it for your purpose. In mimeType use mime type of your attachment. Happy coding.

```
try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(
                "sender@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("reciever@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("subject");

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        URL url = new URL(url);

        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        MimeBodyPart bodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(is);

        multipart.addBodyPart(bodyPart);

        message.setContent(multipart);
        message.addHeader("Content-Type", mimeType);
        Transport.send(message);
        logger.info("SENT to" + message.getRecipients(RecipientType.TO));

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        //some implementation
    }
```

Comment: Please add some documentation/explanation.

Comment: I try this code for sending email with web downloaded attachment. You can easily edit it for your pupose. In mimeType use  mime type of your attachment. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

The current java mail implementation goes over the input stream twice: the first pass to detect the encoding for the data and the second one to send the data.

You can prevent the first pass if you specify the encoding using the EncodingAware interface. The supplied DataSource should implement this interface. Here is an example:

```
public class AttachementDataSource implements javax.activation.DataSource, javax.mail.EncodingAware {

    private final InputStreamSource inputStreamSource; 
    
    public AttachementDataSource(InputStreamSource inputStreamSource) {
        this.inputStreamSource = inputStreamSource;
    }
    
    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return inputStreamSource.getInputStream();
    }

    @Override
    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Read-only javax.activation.DataSource");
    }

    @Override
    public String getContentType() {
        return "application/octet-stream";
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "inline";
    }

    @Override
    public String getEncoding() {
        return "base64";
    }
}
```