# Error While Sending An E-Mail Through Python

Tags: python, email

My code is:

```
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587) #587-> port no
##ALLOWED: https://www.google.com/settings/lesssecureapps
server.starttls()
print("Connected with Gmail Server")
pwd = open("pass.txt").read()
server.login("prateeek.hitman007@gmail.com",pwd)
server.sendmail("prateeek.hitman007@gmail.com","prateekpriyadarshi1328@gmail.com","I miss you 
Prateek")
```

The Following Output is :

```
Connected with Gmail Server
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python Edufavrica/Day11/email_backend.py", line 23, in <module>
    server.login("prateeek.hitman007@gmail.com",pwd)
  File "C:\Users\Prateek Priyadarshi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 730, in login
    raise last_exception
  File "C:\Users\Prateek Priyadarshi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 721, in login
    initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)
  File "C:\Users\Prateek Priyadarshi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 642, in auth
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials h14sm7287809pfq.46 - gsmtp')
```

Please Help me in resolving this error!!

Comment: The error is pretty clear, the username or password are incorrect.

Comment: Try stripping whitespace from the password: `pwd = open("pass.txt").read().strip()`

Comment: No, username and password are correct and i stripped whitespace from password and now this error is showing...                                                                       
           message = MIMEMultiPart() #message contains the predefined dictionary
NameError: name 'MIMEMultiPart' is not defined

Comment: Do you have `from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart` in your script?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38825943/mimemultipart-mimetext-mimebase-and-payloads-for-sending-email-with-file-atta

Comment: I added from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart in my script and nothing changed it is showing the same username and password not accepted also I pasted the above code from the link and this error came out : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.MIMEText'

Comment: That has nothing to do with the authentication, it was to fix the error `name MIMEMultipart is not defined`

Comment: Yes I added email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart it is showing error from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.MIMEMultipart' then i saw some other fixes someone told to use from email.mime.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart it is showing this error .. from email.mime.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.mime.MIMEMultipart' ... I think there is no function defined for MIMEMultipart in _init_.py