# Gmail Api nodeJS Content-Transfer-Encoding quoted-printable not working

Tags: node.js, email, gmail, gmail-api

Problem: Whenever I send a plain text email using the official google api node package (googleapis), I get line breaks around sentences longer than around 70 characters.

```
var headersObj = {
  "To": toEmail,
  "Subject": subject,
  "From": fromEmail,
  "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
  //"Content-Transfer-Encoding": "quoted-printable"
}

for(var header in headersObj) {
  email += header += ": " + headersObj[header] + "\r\n";
}

email += "\r\n" + message;
gmail.users.messages.send({
  userId: 'me',
  auth: oauth2Client,
  resource: {
    raw: btoa(email).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_')
  }
}, function (err, response) {
  if(err) {
    reject(err);
  }else{
    resolve(response);
  }
});
```

I heard I needed to change "Content-Transfer-Encoding" but that only works on html emails. What about plain text emails? I've been searching for months for an answer. Any suggestions, ideas, or solutions?

[image]

Please notice any line longer than 70 characters automatically breaks. Why does this behavior happen and how to solve it?

Comment: You may check on this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28531705/5832311) that discussed [Content-Transfer-Encoding](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/5_Content-Transfer-Encoding.html). It stated that the `quoted-printable` encoding is designed to handle this. It defines that lines will be no greater than 76 characters, and that line breaks will be represented using special characters. *Quoted Printable, because of the escaping and short lines, is much harder to read by a human than  `7bit` or `8bit`, but it does support a much wider range of possible content.*

Comment: Great! Thank you for your quick response. So is it impossible to send a plain-text email with lines greater than 76 characters?