# Spam Assassin reports PP_MIME_FAKE_ASCII_TEXT MIME text/plain claims to be ASCII but isn't

Tags: gmail, sendgrid, email-spam, spamassassin

When emailing via Sendgrid SMTP from Gmail using https://www.mail-tester.com/ it reports SpamAssassin says "PP_MIME_FAKE_ASCII_TEXT MIME text/plain claims to be ASCII but isn't".

Sending the same content from the Gmail address via Gmail's SMTP servers to mail tester does not give this error.

What is going on? How do I fix this error?

Update 2021-03-07 Sendgrid say they require the "SMTP payload" sent from Gmail to their SMTP server. Any suggestions how I can get this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An email entity that claims to be 7bit text contains 8bit characters.

Maybe Google is fixing it for you and sendgrid isn’t.

Check the source of the email you are sending and compare it with what you receive from Google.

Comment: Thanks great idea. Are there any good online tools to check? And to clarify should I be checking it is of type ASCII or 7bit or 8bit?

Comment: What matters is that is the content is coherent with the declaration. If it says 7bit then it should not contain 8bit chars. 

You can read here about the encoding options in email: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25710599/content-transfer-encoding-7bit-or-8-bit#28531705

Comment: That's great thanks! Do you have any suggestions how we check and try to remove any 8bit characters which sendgrid must either be not removing or adding?

Comment: How are you creating these emails? How are you sending them to sendgrid?

Comment: Hi Rodolfo thanks for the reply. I'm using gmail to send to Sendgrid's SMTP server smtp.sendgrid.net using my API key.

Comment: Did you try to send and empty email?

Comment: That's a great idea!