# Compress and zip file from string

Tags: c#, csv, zip

I have a big csv that I need to send by email, the file must be compressed otherwise it might hit the max limit of the smtp server. I'm generating the csv in memory based on a database query.

I was trying to use the answer on this question [C# Compress and zip csv from stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44484786/c-sharp-compress-and-zip-csv-from-stream/44485099?noredirect=1#comment105011159_44485099). but it didn't work(possibly because of the different c# version, I'm using .net core 2.2)

The final csv is a string which I then convert to a Stream and pass it to the extensions of the answer the question.

The code I'm using from the answer(slight adapted):

```
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public Stream FileStream { get; set; }
    }

    public static class ZipArchiveExtensions
    {

        public static Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            writer.Write(s);
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;
            return stream;
        }

        public static Stream Compress(this FileModel file) => Compress(new FileModel[] { file });
        public static Stream Compress(this IEnumerable<FileModel> files)
        {
            if (files.Any())
            {
                var ms = new MemoryStream();
                var archive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, false);
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    var entry = archive.add(file);
                }
                ms.Position = 0;
                return ms;
            }
            return null;
        }

        private static ZipArchiveEntry add(this ZipArchive archive, FileModel file)
        {
            var entry = archive.CreateEntry(file.FileName, CompressionLevel.Fastest);
            using (var stream = entry.Open())
            {
                file.FileStream.CopyTo(stream);
                // stream.Position = 0;
                stream.Close();
            }
            return entry;
        }
    }
```

How I'm using the code:

```
                var stream = ZipArchiveExtensions.GenerateStreamFromString(csvStr);
                var file = new FileModel { FileName = reportName + ".csv", FileStream = stream };
                var compressedFile = file.Compress();

                var attachment = new Attachment(compressedFile, reportName + ".zip");
                await this._emailService.SendMessageAsync(reportRequest.MailTo, reportName, null, new[] { attachment });
```

For some reason the result zip file on the email is invalid.

Comment: What if you store the Zip locally instead? What is the input?

Comment: You cannot send binary data over email.  You need to convert to a Base 64 String.

Comment: @Christopher if I store the file locally it will still be invalid, the input is a string formatted as csv. Something like ```THIS;IS;AN;EXAMPLE;```

Comment: @jdweng That's not necessarily true. See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/3384096/56778.

Comment: @Jim Mischel : There is nothing at that link the refers to binary.  Just the difference between 7 bit ASCII characters and 8 bit ASCII characters.

Comment: @jdweng Hmmm ... I could have sworn I saw something about binary attachments not requiring conversion. Can't find it now. Weird. Perhaps I mis-read something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ZipArchive` object has to be disposed to properly write its content to its underlying stream. Additionally, you have to set the `leaveOpen` flag to true so upon disposing the archive, the `compressedFile` will not be closed.

```
public static Stream Compress(this IEnumerable<FileModel> files)
{
    if (files.Any())
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, leaveOpen: true))
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                var entry = archive.add(file);
            }
        }        
        ms.Position = 0;
        return ms;
    }
    return null;
}
```